# Issue when an ui-calendar is first hid and then showed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, angular-ui

I met a strange issue with ui-calendar when your calendar is first hid and then displayed.
On Github, a similar issue was encountered but using tabs (which I don't use) : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/28

I edited a JsFiddle to explicit the issue :
http://jsfiddle.net/fECuY/20/

```
<div ng-show="test">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ui-calendar="calendar" config="uiconfig.calendar" ng-model="events"></div>
</div>
```

If you click on the button, a second calendar should be displayed, but its 'header' only is render. If we try to render the calendar when the variable, linked to the ng-show attribute, is changed, the ng-show is not updated already, so even with a DOM manipulation, there is no way to call fullCalendar() on this element.

So how can I render properly my calendar when I want it to be displayed ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the way `ng-show` works. It is essentially using a `display: none` to hide the element. This creates issues with how the calendar shows itself. The solution is to use `ng-if`instead, which will generate the calendar when it is true. See the comment in the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/51#issuecomment-29580656).